# Javascript doesn't add the class

Tags: javascript

I just started learning javascript and i have a piece of code that is not working and i can't figure out what is wrong.

I have already checked the names of everything if they are spelled correctly multiple times.

```
function beautify() {
  document.write("ja");
  var item = document.getElementById("top");    
  item.classList.add("beautiful");
  return;
}
```

Comment: You don't have an element with id 'top' in the stnippet you've provided. This will cause an error "cannot read property 'classlist' of null".

Comment: What errors do you get? Please post a [mcve]

Comment: `document.write` clears everything. i guess

Comment: Show the html for the element

Comment: You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to provide a runnable example of the code.

Comment: what is the "document.write("ja") line for ? I feels like it cleans the whole page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to https://javascript.info

A very good website to refer.

```js
document.body.innerHTML = "<button onclick='beautify()'>Click Me</button>"; 
document.body.innerHTML += "<h1 id='top'>Manish</h1>"; 

function beautify()
{ 
var item = document.getElementById("top");  
item.classList.add("beautiful");
}
```

```css
.beautiful{
  color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To debug the code and try to understand the problem, i would use console.log().

```
function beautify(){ 
        console.log('function is executed');
        document.write("ja");
        var item = document.getElementById("top");  

        item.classList.add("beautiful");
        return;
}
beautify();
```

So you execute the function - by calling function_name(); - after you have declared it, and check if the console.log() writes something through your browser console. For example on Firefox or Chrome by pressing F12 you can access it.

EDIT: I forgot to mention you can also see Javascript errors through the console in case